# How to set border-radius to make a circled letter?

Tags: html, css, border

I tried to insert into my site a border-radius. It should look like:

[image]

I use Font Awesome and Bootstrap (in Fiddle I can’t insert it). This is how I tried to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/24oehpeh/

This is the code:

```css
 .ikonka:hover{   
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ikonka">f</div>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't define a width...

Comment: The div stretches the whole width of the page, resulting in the wide ellipse. Either use a span, or give the div a width.

Comment: I got it. It was really problem with width.

Comment: When linking things in jsfiddle just you the path like this `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` you inserted the html that needs to be in the `<head>` section of an HTML page.

Comment: here is your solution http://jsfiddle.net/24oehpeh/7/

Answer (score 4):

I choosed to use the pseudo element "before" for this solution.

It gives you the benefit like "a second element", where you can more freely style it without making to many tricks with the main element.

<sup>**Updated, has a *perfectly round* circle now.. :)**</sup>

```css
.ikonka {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    /*padding: 4px 10px;   removed */
    background-color: black;
    color: white;    
    width: 24px;          /* added */
    height: 24px;         /* added */
    line-height: 24px;    /* added */
    text-align: center;   /* added */
}
.ikonka:hover:before {
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius:100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ikonka">f</div>
```

Comment: Somehow it looks a bit… ovoid.

Comment: It’d be great if egg-shape is desired, but in the OP’s case, I think he wished for an actual circle shape, meaning a perfect round ring. Anyway, it can easily be helped by adding square width and height dimensions.

Comment: @dakab So I got a few minutes and fixed my "egg shape" :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a width on your element. As it stands, the content `f` is wrapped in a div, which is a block level element. This will occupy maximum horizontal space available.

```css
 .ikonka {
    border: #fff 2px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
}

 .ikonka:hover {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="ikonka">f</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

- The `div` must not be set to auto-width (which would be 100%).
- The border should be transparent, so there are two pixels of invisible border.
- A border radius of 50% suffices since it bends half of each side.
- To make it look like your example, some font styling is necessary.
- Result:
  [image: rendering of below snippet]

```css
body{ background-color:#2C2F34; }

.ikonka{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius:50%;
    color:white;
    cursor:default;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.ikonka:hover{ border-color:white; }
```

```html
<div class="ikonka">f</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```css
.ikonka:hover{   
    border: 2px solid white;
border-radius:100%;
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.ikonka {
        width: 100px;
height: 72px;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;

font-size: 51px;

color: white;
vertical-align: middle;

position: relative;

display: inline-block;
padding: 16px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ikonka">f</div>
```